# While não está parando quando deveria

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="row">
 <?
 $tag = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['categoria']);
 $result = $connection -> query("select * from produtos where tags like '%$tag%' and online='0' order by id limit 4");
 while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     $id = $row['id'];
     $titulo = $row['titulo'];
     $resumo = $row['resumo'];
     $imagem = $row['imagem'];
 ?>
    <div class="grid_3">
        <div class="box2 wrap1 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
            <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>"><img class="first" src="<?=$imagem?>" alt=""/></a>
            <div class="caption bggreen equal">
                <h6 class="text_3 colorblue">
                    <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>""><?=$titulo?></a>
                </h6>
                <br>
                <p class="colorwhite">
                <?=$resumo?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?
     }
     $result -> free();
    ?>

    </div>
```

A `<div class="row">` só aceita 4 caixas, como faço para não ter que repetir essa div sempre que os produtos ultrapassarem esse mesmo número? Coloco a div dentro do while ou tenho que fazer de outra forma?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi o que você quer você estava indo para o caminho certo, só precisava adicionar um contador para saber quando parar:

```
<?
$tag = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['categoria']);
$result = $connection -> query("select * from produtos where tags like '%$tag%' and online='0' order by id limit 4");
$contador = 0;
while ($contador < 4 && ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
    $resumo = $row['resumo'];
    $imagem = $row['imagem'];
?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid_3">
            <div class="box2 wrap1 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>"><img class="first" src="<?=$imagem?>" alt=""/></a>
                <div class="caption bggreen equal">
                    <h6 class="text_3 colorblue">
                        <a href="verproduto.php?id=<?=$id?>""><?=$titulo?></a>
                    </h6>
                    <br>
                    <p class="colorwhite">
                         <?=$resumo?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?
    $contador++;
}
$result -> free();
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Loop.php).

Comment: Vou experimentar e ver se resulta, obrigado

Comment: Já experimentei essa alteração mas ele agora so me imprime 1 produto por linha, ou seja, está a imprimir um produto por cada <div class="row">. Eu preciso que ele imprima 4 produtos por linha e ao chegar ao 4 cria uma nova linha

Comment: Aí é problema de CSS e não de PHP, são coisas distintas.

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema bigown, obrigado pela ajuda na mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi o problema. Bastava apenas retirar o `limit 4` na query. Visto que estou a usar grelhas e elas estão com um `float: left` então automaticamente as caixas mudam de linha.